# Get the per-row number of keys of hstore data in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, hstore

I have a hstore column in my postgresql database. Each row of the database has a different number of keys/values in the hstore-column. How can i get the number of keys/values for each row?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select hstore_column, 
       array_length(akeys(hstore_column), 1) as num_keys
from the_table
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if postgres is smart enough to not materialize the array?

Answer (score 4):

You can use one of [`hstore` functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE), to convert `hstore` to another data type that can retrieve number of elements. For instance, you can use `avalue` to count the number of keys on a `hstore` value:

```
SELECT id, array_length(avals(my_hstore_field), 1) AS count_keys
FROM mytable;
```

On the docs there is a nice example to get all the keys and the number of occurrences of it that may be useful for you:

```
SELECT key, count(*) FROM
  (SELECT (each(h)).key FROM testhstore) AS stat
  GROUP BY key
  ORDER BY count DESC, key;
```

Comment: This gives the total count of keys. That's nice, too. But i needed the number of keys per row. But thank you anyhow.

Comment: @Julian, that is what that the first query gives you. But I see the other answer is almost the same.